# Cache CSS and Javascript in the background or load it from the application

Tags: java, javascript, android, css, webview

My application uses `Webview` for the website which has quite lots of CSS and Javascript (about 0.5 MB). Is it possible:

- To cache all the CSS and Javascript before user opens the
  application?
- If not, maybe it's possible to cache the CSS and Javascript for a
  very long time (because it changes very rarely) after user opens the
  application for the first time?
- Or maybe it's possible to put .js and .css files in the Android
  folders, so it would load it from the files instead of connecting to
  the server?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be using HTML5 localStorage. Something like this (not tested):

```
function loadScripts() {
    var scriptURL   = '/myscript.js',
        cssURL      = '/mycss.css',
        jsXHR,
        cssXHR;

    var applyStyleAndScript = function(styleText, scriptText) {
        var styleTag    = document.createElement('style'),
            scriptTag   = document.createElement('script');

        styleTag.innerText = styleText;
        document.body.appendChild(styleTag);

        scriptTag.innerText = jsText;
        document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
    }

    if (localStorage && localStorage[scriptURL] && localStorage[cssURL]) {
        applyStyleAndScript(localStorage[cssURL], localStorage[scriptURL]);
    } else {
        cssXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        jsXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

        cssXHR.open('GET', cssURL);
        cssXHR.onload = function(e) {
            var cssText = e.target.responseText;

            if (localStorage) localStorage[cssURL] = cssText;

            jsXHR.open('GET', scriptURL);
            jsXHR.onload = function(e) {
                var jsText = e.target.responseText;

                if (localStorage) localStorage[scriptURL] = jsText;

                applyStyleAndScript(cssText, jsText);
            }

            jsXHR.send();
        }

        cssXHR.send();
    }
}
```